# Android WebView opens uTorrent

Tags: android, webview

When utorrent is installed on phone, clicking on a link in app webview opens utorrent instead of loading link!

even using javascript doesn't solve the problem:

```
window.location.href='index.html'
```

it still brings up utorrent.

There's no problem if utorrent is not installed.

I couldn't find anything about this in web.

What is the problem?

Comment: I wonder who voted to close and why!?

Comment: What does your `WebViewClient` do in `shouldOverrideUrlLoading()`?

Comment: I didn't add anything to WebViewClient and I don't know much about it. @CommonsWare

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to create a `WebViewClient` to prevent that behavior:

```
public class webViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }
}
```

And then set it to your `WebView` like this:

```
webview.setWebViewClient(new webViewClient());
```

Comment: This method works, but somehow breaks history.back() in JS. I call it like this this.wv.loadUrl("javascript:history.back()"); it goes back and forward to the two last pages.

Answer (score 2):

When the user clicks on an ordinary link in a `WebView`, Android, by default, will start an `ACTION_VIEW` `Intent` on the URL in the link. Typically, this will bring up the user's default Web browser, though in some cases it may bring up another app, as apparently is the case here.

If you do not want the default behavior, you need to create an instance of a `WebViewClient` subclass, where you implement `shouldOverrideUrlLoading()` to do something else instead of the default behavior. You then attach the `WebViewClient` instance to the `WebView` via `setWebViewClient()`.

Comment: When uTorrent is not installed it loads the link in the webview not the browser and I don't even define shouldOverrideUrlLoading(). but uTorrent get the click if it's installed.

Comment: @Ali: "When uTorrent is not installed it loads the link in the webview not the browser" -- no, it does not, unless you use a `WebViewClient`, if it is an ordinary link.

Answer (score -1):

uTorrent app may specify an activity that can be opened by an intent containing an html link. If you don't have anything else that can open links (ie. some kind of browser), or if you've set uTorrent as default app to launch for links, it will open automatically.

Try going to Settings > Apps and click on uTorrent. If you can, click the "clear defaults" button, then try opening your link again.

Comment: I want to put this app on google play. It's much better if I can solve it from inside the app.

Comment: I went to utorrent config page, it says: "No defaults set" and the button is disabled.